# Compile Xerces-C Android

Tags: android, xerces-c, android-make

I am trying to compile the library of Xercesc-c but the truth is that I can not and the things that I have found have not helped me.
I'm trying to do this with Android-make but I really do not know if it is possible to compile this for APP_ABI: = armeabi-v7a, I would like to obtain a .so or a static library. But the truth is that all my results are unsuccessful. The reason why I have to use this library is because it is dependent on another one and I am trying to migrate to android to be able to make it work.

Has anyone been successful trying to compile this for android?

I downloaded the github project from here https://github.com/pelya/commandergenius/tree/sdl_android/project/jni/xerces, but due to my limited knowledge I could not compile it.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use xerces as opposed to something provided natively in Android like [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml)?

Comment: Yes, I have a library that was written in C ++ and has Xerces dependency, so I have to have compiled the Xerces library to compile the C ++ library

Comment: @MichaelKrause have you succesfully compile Xerces for android?

Comment: No - I haven't tried.  I wonder if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651804/xerces-on-android) might help you?

Comment: Nope. But thanks @MichaelKrause