# How to use the --core-library option in eclipse/Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jython

Trying to build a project, the project is Jythonroid. I managed to troubleshoot all the errors but it won't compile. The interface suggests using the --core-library option. Any idea how to set this flag in eclipse for Android.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

I think this has been answered here:
[Android core library error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839435/android-core-library-error)

You **can't** add --core-library using Eclipse.