# "--core-library" error integrating HttpUnit with android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, http-unit

I am trying to run a simple project as a demo of HttpUnit on android. The code does not compile and gives this error

```
Android Dex: [HttpUnitAndroid] the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Android Dex: [HttpUnitAndroid] If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Android Dex: [HttpUnitAndroid] building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Android Dex: [HttpUnitAndroid] will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Android Dex: [HttpUnitAndroid] prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Android Dex: [HttpUnitAndroid] application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Android Dex: [HttpUnitAndroid] system. You will be to blame for this problem.
```

So how do I put this "--core-library" option so that it compiles atleast? I cant seem to find this option in intellij idea. Nor do I think its in eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839435/android-core-library-error has a discussion on this