# --core-library error with build tools android (Eclipse)[solved with android studio]

Tags: android, eclipse, build-tools, dx

I am trying to build an apk with `xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar` **using eclipse without Maven**. But unfortunately it gives following error.

```
trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
```

look at this image for error - 
[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7lwjk96eyucm5c/screenwallet.png?dl=0)

I follwed https://stackoverflow.com/a/11090774/1602333 and put this

```
exec java $javaOpts -jar "$jarpath" --core-library "$@"
```

[Dx File Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zoclelk2xhocc52/screendx.png?dl=0)

in my build tools (21.1.2) dx file. But with no luck , error still remains.I have only 1 build tools (21.1.2).
Any help ?

Comment: Hello, surprisingly the solution --core-library doesn't work with eclipse but does work with android studio with gradle. thank You,

Comment: You can close you own question by putting the solution in the answer box provided. Editing the question to include the word "solved" still causes the question to remain in the "unsolved" pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally , I moved to android studio as no luck building it with eclipse.
And it runs great.