# Xerces in Android Studio

Tags: android, spring, android-studio, gradle, xerces

I'm trying to use spring-context in an Android project and have gotten as far as trying to load a context file. I'm getting this error:

> Your JAXP provider ... does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 or below with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.

I've found partial answers from a couple years ago indicating the fix is to include Xerces in my project.

I'm using Android Studio, which forces me to use Gradle. I can't for the life of me figure out what to use as the classpath to include Xerces in Gradle. Does anyone know what it is? Is Xerces even available to Gradle? Is there some newer, easier fix that I've missed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven  see top answer here.. that is the maven artifact . then googl maven artifacts gradle and u should figure it all out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was that the only thing you wanted? :)

```
'xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0'
```

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer because it does answer the quesiton posed. Unfortunately, adding this now causes the dreaded preDexDebug exit problem.

Comment: This error occurs because Xerces extends the core library `javax.*`. Try using Xerces-for-Android.

Answer (score 1):

Xerces extends the core library `javax.*`. Extending core libraries is not allowed in Android. However you can use `--core-library` to suppress these warnings. However, this is not recommended. For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11090774/5320080).

You can overcome this problem by repackaging the needed classes with a tool like *JarJar*.  This has been done in the [Xerces-for-Android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/xerces-for-android/), wherein the package `mf` is placed above the "normal" Xerces packages.

Comment: I included the essential parts of the referenced answer.

Comment: Grate but I didn't down vote your answer I just mark it as link