# Xerces + Gradle = preDexDebug errors

Tags: android, spring, gradle, xerces

I'm trying to add spring-context to a project in Android Studio. I have to bring in Xerces so Spring can parse my context file correctly, but that leads to this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

`gradlew assembleDebug` says the problem is:

> trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class"

and then adds a long, supercilious lecture about why compiling core libraries is a bad thing. Okay, so how do I fix this?

One thing that didn't work was trying to exclude the offending module:

```
compile ('xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0') {
    exclude module: 'xml-apis'
}
```

This led to much more extensive compile errors.

Another thing that didn't work was [following the instructions for this Gradle JarJar plugin](https://github.com/vRallev/jarjar-gradle), which led to:

> Could not find property 'preBuild' on task set.

I'm about ready to give up and just write my own parser from scratch. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Are you using 32 bit system or 64 bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Xerces extends the core library `javax` which leads to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11090774/5320080) in Android.

You can overcome this problem by repackaging the needed classes with a tool like *JarJar*.  This has been done in the [Xerces-for-Android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/xerces-for-android/), wherein the package `mf` is placed above the "normal" Xerces packages.